# ASIHTTPRequest Cache disable

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, httprequest, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest for to communicate an iOS app with the server. I've been using the library in many other projects until now and I haven't had any problem.

But now, the application that I'm coding has 3 different methods for Log in/sign up:

1. Normal login (username/password)
2. Connect with Facebook
3. Connect with RunKeeper

Each one of those methods works nice if you use them separately. For example I can do a normal login with username and password, I get this information from the user and I send It to the server using HTTPRequest library and the server gives me a valid access_token to log in with no problem. Same with Facebook or runKeeper.

But if I do the following steps anything works:

1. I log in with Facebok or RunKeeper (doesn't matter which one) using an account that it's already linked to a certain user (we can call him X).
2. I request to Facebook/RunKeeper the access_token and the userID of the user and I send this information to my server.
3. My server gives me a valid access_token for the user X and I load the dashboard with his information.
4. The user X Logs out and I clear all the information in NSUserDefaults and synchronize it.
5. The user Y logs in using using his username and password (log in method number 1).
6. My server gives me a valid access_token for the user Y and I load the dashboard with his information.
7. The user Y logs out and I clear all the stored data in NSUserDefaults and synchronize it.
8. Finally any other user (Z for example) logs in again using Facebook/runKeeper.
9. I get all the information required from the social network and I send it to my server.
10. My server gives me a valid access_token and I load the dashboard, but it's not the dashboard of the user Z, It's the dashboard from the last user that has logged in using username/password.

I know that reading those steps you can think that It's a problem with the server, but i did some tests using cURL and the response for the tokens are always correct. Then I thought that it could be some problem in the iOS App but I couldn't see anything with the breakpoints and the NSLogs i did.

The i read about the cache in the ASIHttpRequest library and I added thos two lines of code in all my requests to the server for disabling all the cache system but it didn't work:

```
[request setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Cache-Control" value:@"no-cache"];
```

I don't know if anyone of you had the same problem or If you've got any idea of what can I try, but It will be very appreciated.

If you need more information just tell me an i'll see what can i do

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the important advice to stop use ASIHTTPRequest because it's not working well with ios 7

i'm facing many issues with ios 7 after release it to production

you can use this instead 
[AFNetwork](http://afnetworking.com/)

Comment: Hi Mhisham! Thanks for the answer! I tried to use AFNetworking but It doesn't work 

Comment: hope it help [AFNetwork Tutorial in raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

Comment: I just found the error! It seems that the server was sending me a cookie that was giving some problems  Hopefully the issue is solved now using ASIHTTPRequest  Thanks for your help!!